# git project not showing on github page

Tags: git, github

I recently made a project from scratch and uploaded into GitHub .After pushing i my files did not get uploaded into the folder i created in GitHub. However showing a notification to compare and pull requests. When I press compare and pull request page shows the code with no option to compare and pull request. This happens when I only send files from scratch if contribute to any other PROJECT no issues. Also, I can upload files directly to Github (not via terminal using upload button)

[image]

Attaching screenshot

[image]

Comment: The answer is right there in the first screenshot. All you have to do is look at what the GitHub web interface is showing you.

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing your code to a branch named `master` (and a branch named `navbar`), but the default branch GitHub created for your project is named `main`.

You can also go into your project settings and to change which branch is the default that is shown when you initially visit the web interface.

Above the list of project files, there is a drop down menu that you can use to choose which branch you are currently looking at.

Comment: Thanks for helping I am a beginner at this .it solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

It's because you pushed it to other branches .
Click the branches menu and you'll get the 3 options

Comment: Thanks for helping I am a beginner at this .it solved my issue